# In a random sequence of N letters, what is the expected number of occurrences of a specific M-letter sequence?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

In a random sequence of N letters, what is the expected number of occurrences of a specific M-letter sequence?

**Edit:**

As a specific example, in a single-stranded DNA having N letters, what is the expected number of occurrences of the letter "GG"?

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/253576/expected-number-of-substring-in-random-string

Comment: @d.k.o. thanks for the comment. However, that is not the question I'm asking here. I'm specifically talking about a particular M-letter word.

Comment: @d.k.o. see my edit also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ is your random variable (number of occurrences), then you can write it as:

$$X=X_1+X_2+\ldots+X_{N-M+1}$$

where each $X_i$ is the indicator:

$$X_i=\begin{cases}1&\text{there is a desired sequence starting at index }i\\0&\text{there isn't}\end{cases}$$

Now, for all $i=1,2,\ldots,N-M+1$:

$$E(X_i)=\mathcal P(\text{there is a desired sequence starting at index }i)=p$$

where $p$ depends on the exact probabilities of different symbols. If you have $k$ symbols, equally probable, then $p=\frac{1}{k^M}$. In your DNA example, $p=\frac{1}{4^2}=\frac{1}{16}$.

By linearity of expectation:

$$E(X)=\sum_{i=1}^{N-M+1} E(X_i)=(N-M+1)p$$

which is a curious result, as one would intuitively expect that it would hold if the individual random variables were independent (and we know that $X_i$ are definitely *not* independent). However, linearity of expectation is satisfied *even for random variables that are not independent*.

**Answer**: Applying the above formula for $p=\frac{1}{16}$ and $M=2$, we get that the expected number of DNA pairs GG in sequence of length $N$ is $\frac{1}{16}(N-1)$.

**Note**: For avoidance of confusion, just one more remark on counting. Let's take the DNA example with, say $N=4$, and let the sequence be GGGA. That sequence has *two* occurrences of GG, at positions $1$ and $2$, respectively, and that is how it went into the above calculation. If we were counting *something else* (e.g. sequences of G's of length $\ge 2$), then the calculation would be completely different.